# Is it possible to pause a running java application, fix the issues, recompile it and then run it from the spot that it was paused?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Selenium and Java to write tests. I was wondering if there is any way that I can run my code in debug mode and then if there is any issue in the code, I pause the application, fix it, recompile it and then run it from the spot that it was paused. My IDE is Eclipse Mars.

Comment: I don't think so. You can modify code that takes place after a break point. That way your application stays paused while you fix an issue. After hitting continue the method the code is under should be re-invoked.

Comment: Have a look at [HotswapAgent](http://www.hotswapagent.org/) (or JRebel if you want to use a commercial product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only in limited cases where the changes to the code are minor. What you are talking about is called hot code replace. The following explanation is taken from the [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F).

> Hot code replace (HCR) is a debugging technique whereby the Eclipse
>   Java debugger transmits new class files over the debugging channel to
>   another JVM. In the case of Eclipse development, this also applies to
>   the VM that runs the runtime workbench. The idea is that you can start
>   a debugging session on a given runtime workbench and change a Java
>   file in your development workbench, and the debugger will replace the
>   code in the receiving VM while it is running. No restart is required,
>   hence the reference to "hot".
>
> HCR has been specifically added as a standard technique to Java to
>   facilitate experimental development and to foster iterative
>   trial-and-error coding. HCR only works when the class signature does
>   not change; you cannot remove or add fields to existing classes, for
>   instance. However, HCR can be used to change the body of a method. HCR
>   is reliably implemented only on 1.4.1 VMs and later, or using any
>   version of the IBM J9 VM. J9 is available in IBM products such as
>   Websphere Studio Device Developer™.
>
> If HCR does not work for you even in a simple Java application and you
>   have confirmed that you are running the application on a supported VM
>   (taking note that the JVM that runs Eclipse may not be the same as the
>   JVM that is running your Java application), you may not have automatic
>   building turned on. **Make sure that 'Project > Build Automatically' is
>   checked.**

Comment: Thanks @AndyThomas. I've added some emphasis to that in the original quote from the Eclipse Wiki.

Comment: During past hours i was looking for a good and complete tutorial for HCR but I failed, do you know any?

Comment: Try this one - http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Comment: could you have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409978/how-to-use-hot-code-replacement-to-correct-my-xpath-of-it-is-incorrect and se if you can help me